# Фильтрация массива с n-ным количеством элементов

Tags: php, массивы, wordpress

У меня есть массив (например, такой). Структура мне неизвестна, я лишь знаю что массив состоит из n-ного количества строк.

```
Array
(
    [workers] => Array
        (
            [worker1] => "John"
            [worker2] => "Matthew"
            [worker3] => "Andrew"

        )
)
```

Стоит задача - отфильтровать строки. К примеру, я могу сделать так -- `'first_name'   => filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'first_name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING )` для строки (одной единственной!). К массиву такое не покатит. Я могу использовать filter_input_array, но тогда в $args придется описывать каждую строку и что применить к ней (какой фильтр). А если таких строк n-ное количество, которое я никак не могу отследить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует множество вариантов фильтрации массивов. Вот один из примеров

```
<?php

$arr = [
    'workers' => [
        'worker1' => '<h6>John</h6>',
        'worker2' => '<h5>Matthew</h5>',
        'worker3' => '<h4>Andrew</h4>'
    ],

    'workers2' => [
        'worker1' => '<h3>John</h3>',
        'worker2' => '<h2>Matthew</h2>',
        'worker3' => [
            'worker1' => '<h3>John</h3>',
            'worker2' => '<h2>Matthew</h2>',
            'worker3' => '<h1>Andrew</h1>'
        ]
    ]
];

// До фильтра
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($arr); echo '</pre>';

array_walk_recursive($arr, function(&$item, $key) {
    $item = strip_tags($item);
});

// После фильтра
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($arr); echo '</pre>';
```